# Accessing controls inside a repeater from another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, pageload, linkbutton

I have a repeater in page A which its `ItemTemplate`contains a `LinkButton` with PostBackUrl= page B. Also, it contains a hidden field which takes its value from the `datasource` associated with the repeater. I want to access this hidden field from page B. In page A when the `LinkButton` is clicked the `sender` object is converted to `LinkButton` then, the instance of `LinkButton` is accessed in the loading event of page B, where I used `NamingContainer` to know which repeater item was clicked and retrieve the value of the hidden field in it. I found this method here:

http://aspadvice.com/blogs/joteke/archive/2007/02/25/Understanding-the-naming-container-hierarchy-of-ASP.NET-databound-controls.aspx

I'm just using it across pages. But it is not working. Here is my code:

Repeater code in page A:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="postsRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="postsSource">

        <HeaderTemplate>

        </HeaderTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="commentsLink" OnClick="viewPost" CssClass="comments_profile_buttons" PostBackUrl="~/comments.aspx">
            <asp:HiddenField ID="psotId" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("postId") %>' />
//other controls...
      </ItemTemplate>
  </Repeater >
```

Onclick method fro the `LinkButton` in Page A:

```
protected void onclickbtn (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
            btn.ID = "itemPointer";  
        }
```

This is the `Onload` event code for page B:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (PreviousPage != null)
            {
                //retrieve the clicked post info: 
                //First access the clicked item in the repeater: 
                LinkButton senderbtn = (LinkButton) PreviousPage.FindControl("btn");
                RepeaterItem clickedItem = (RepeaterItem)senderbtn.NamingContainer; 


                HiddenField postIdHidden = (HiddenField)clickedItem.FindControl("psotId");



            }//end if
```

This is the error that I get:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

which is caused by this line: `RepeaterItem clickedItem = (RepeaterItem)senderbtn.NamingContainer;`

I think the retrieved `ButtonLink` is null, but I couldn't figure out why.

Can anyone please tell me what was the mistake I did?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the error was because you cannot use `PreviousPage` property without using `Server.Transfer`. So, I just removed the PostBackUrl property of the LinkButton and used `Server.Transfer` in the `OnClick` handler of the `LinkButton`.

It's working now.

Thanks.